# T-SQL datetime conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with a 3rd party database, which (for whatever reason) internal stores a date in the format `yyyymm` eg `201212` for `Dec 2012` as an `INT`.

Is there a simple way that I may convert this to a SQL Server `DateTime` type?

I've tried manually converting the above to a char seq of length 6, concatenating this with '01' to get the start of a given month like so:

```
(CONVERT(char(6), Period) + '01')`
```

then wrapping this in a `datetime` conversion:

```
CONVERT(datetime, (CONVERT(char(6), Period) + '01'))
```

but this seems to throw;

> *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string*

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm *hoping* that, for the first 9 months of the year, it's including a padding zero on the month. Can you confirm that though?

Comment: It should be since he said that the date format is YYYYMM

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk - It wouldn't be the first time I encountered a database build by a third party (as the OP is working with here) where they've used an *insane* way of representing dates. That's why I wanted to ask.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error unless there are values in `Period` that *don't* match the format you've given.

Comment: Think you may be right here Damien - I managed to spot some '0's. :/

thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct parameter. Here's the msdn chart http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

In your case, i believe you need to append the '01' and use this

```
declare @val VARCHAR(8)

SET @val = '201212'

set @val = @val + '01'

print CONVERT(DATETIME, @val, 12)
```

12 is the ISO format and will take either yymmdd or yyyymmdd

Comment: I liked the simplicity of this one.  I wrote a function to do the above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
Declare @val as int = 20121231;
select DATEADD (YEAR,@val/10000-1900,DATEADD(MONTH,(@val%10000)/100-1,DATEADD(DAY,@val%100-1,0 )))
```

This is another:

```
Declare @val as int = 20121231;
    Cast(Cast(@val as char(8)) as date)
```

The first is good because you won't have any regional setting dependencies. The second is good because it's brief.

Comment: Nice answer, the input does not have a day part tho.  But that should be easy to adopt.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the stuff :

```
DECLARE @Period INTEGER = 201212 
SELECT  CAST( CAST( @Period * 100 + 1 AS CHAR(8) ) AS DATETIME )
```

Comment: Two problems here: first, the input doesn't have a day, so it is 6 characters long.  Second, casting an `int` to a too short `char` does not return a truncated string but `*`.  [Example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/1767/0)

Comment: Did not notice it was an integer, but the edit of the question has cleared things (edited my answer accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the integer to a `yyyy-mm-dd` style string:

```
select  convert(datetime, 
            left(cast(dt as char(6)),4) + '-' +
            right(cast(dt as char(6)),2) + '-01',
            121) -- 121 = ODBC = yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm (24h)
from    YourTable
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/110cd/9/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some simple maths, avoiding strings as much as possible:

```
declare @Start int
set @Start = 201212

select DATEADD(month,((@Start/100)-1970)*12 + (@Start%100-1),'19700101')
```

That being said, I'd have expected what you originally posted to work, since `YYYYMMDD` is an unambiguous format.

---

If you're selecting these values from a table that may contain a range of values, only some of which are these values, and you're relying on the `WHERE` clause to filter out invalid ones before the conversion occurs, you're out of luck - SQL Server has a nasty habit of moving operations around, and can apply filters and conversions in any order it likes.

If this is the case, move the filtering step (to exclude invalid `Period` values) into a separate query that populates a table variable or temp table, then perform the conversion on those values in a separate query.

Answer (score 0):

you can use as below:

```
Select CAST( CAST(datepart(year,getdate()) AS VARCHAR(4))+ CAST (datepart(MONTH,getdate()) as VARCHAR(2)) AS INT) as YYYYMM
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following to work quite well.
Assuming your INT for the date is in YYYYMM format.
First multiply by 100, then add 1 (this results in an INT with a DD of 01) so you now have YYYYMMDD instead of YYYYMM.
Then cast to CHAR(8) before casting to DATETIME.
Hope it works for you.

```
DECLARE @SourceDT   INT = 201212
SELECT CAST( CAST((@SourceDT * 100) + 1 AS CHAR(8)) AS DATETIME)
```