# SQL: Next Month of Integer Date and return an Integer

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a column startMonth as Integer, for example `199812`

I need to have the next month of it and return an integer `199901`. How to handle this in SQL in one line?

Similar to

```
SELECT NEXTMONTH(199812)
```

will display `199901`

Comment: What RDBMS are you running?

Comment: I have updated the problem, it is running in Sybase

Comment: What Sybase product? ASE? SQLAnywhere?

Comment: I tried this and succeed: CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(VARCHAR,startMonth*100+1)),112) AS INT)/100

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102793/t-sql-datetime-conversion

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when startMonth % 100 = 12
            then startMonth - 11 + 100
            else startMonth + 1
       end
```

Comment: The `when startMonth % 12 = 0` should be: `when startMonth % 100 = 12`

Comment: That won't work, `201408 % 12 = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about sybase syntax, but my approach would be:

1. cast your integer to a string
2. append 01 to the end
3. cast the result to a date
4. add a month
5. extract the year and month and cast them to strings.
6. concatonate them and then cast them to an int.

Comment: I tried this and succeeded: CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(VARCHAR,startMonth*100+1)),112) AS INT)/100